# How to access members inside vector of structure

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector, stdoptional

I have a member variable which is of type vector of structure and which is defined as std::optional, so how do I access members inside the structure.

Example:

```
std::optional<std::vector<demoStruct>> mem_variable;

struct demoStruct
{
int a;
float b;
};
```

So how do i access 'a' and 'b' using mem_variable;

Comment: First you have to make sure that `mem_variable` really have a value (it *is* optional after all). Then you have to figure out which of the vectors element you want. Then you print the values of that element like any other structure.

Comment: And note that in your code it's the *vector* that is optional, not the values inside the vector. That usually makes no sense. Perhaps you wanted a vector of optional values (like `std::vector<std::optional<demoStruct>>`)?

Comment: do you know how to access the value in an `optional` ? do you know how to access an element of a `vector`? Which part did you not find in documentation? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it contains the optional value and then you can dereference it.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

struct demoStruct {
    int a;
    float b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<demoStruct> foo{{1,2.f}, {3,4.f}};

    std::optional<std::vector<demoStruct>> mem_variable = foo;

    if(mem_variable) { // check that it contains a vector<demoStruct>

        // dereference the optional to get the stored value
        std::vector<demoStruct>& value_ref = *mem_variable;

        // display the contents of the vector
        for(demoStruct& ds : value_ref) {
            std::cout << ds.a << ',' << ds.b << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,2
3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be helpful, I added a instance to the vector and printed one value, although I'm not sure you are properly using `optional`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

struct demoStruct
{
int a;
float b;
};

int main()
{
    //Create an instance
    demoStruct  example;
    example.a = 42;
    example.b = 43.0;

    std::optional<std::vector<demoStruct>> mem_variable;
    //Add created instance to vector
    mem_variable->push_back(example);
    std::cout << mem_variable->at(0).a; // prints 42


    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the [cpp referenec page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) it's written that `operator->` and `operator*`    accesses the contained value